# require vm2 using electron and webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, electron

I encounter an error when I try to import the `vm2` module inside the Electron renderer process using Webpack.

```
import fs from 'fs'

console.log('ok')

const { NodeVM } = require('vm2')

console.log('ko')
```

Here is the error, displayed by Webpack:

```
WARNING in ./~/vm2/lib/main.js
Critical dependencies:
180:26-33 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
335:15-22 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
367:26-33 require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./~/vm2/lib/main.js 180:26-33 335:15-22 367:26-33

WARNING in ./~/vm2/lib/sandbox.js
Module parse failed: /Users/guillaume/Voyager/Voyager/node_modules/vm2/lib/sandbox.js 'return' outside of function (20:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: 'return' outside of function (20:0)
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/guillaume/Voyager/Voyager/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:923:13)
    at Parser.pp.parseReturnStatement (/Users/guillaume/Voyager/Voyager/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1864:74)
```

I tried excluding the node_modules folder from my webpack config:

```
module: {

    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      include: PATHS.app,
      loader: 'babel',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        presets: [ 'es2015', 'react', 'stage-1' ],
        plugins: [ 'add-module-exports', 'transform-decorators-legacy' ],
      },
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: [ 'style', 'css', 'postcss-loader?parser=postcss-scss' ],
      include: PATHS.app,
    }],
  }
```

But it does not seem to work. the first `console.log` appears, not the second one.
I added the target as well using `webpack-target-electron-renderer`. Same..

Finally, when I add `externals: [/vm2/]`, Webpack does not throw any error, but the renderer console says `Uncaught ReferenceError: vm2 is not defined`

I would guess it has something to do with the fact that `vm2` is using `require` dynamically and webpack doesn't like that (because importing `fs` is working fine)

Where does that problem come from and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using the build in `target: electron`. That renderer was eventually pulled into core. https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/314c897682b556845fea36d329de8016d1740900/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js#L115-L179